# Resend same email in ActionMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

I need to send big amount of emails. Building email in this case is quite heavy task, so I'm trying to cache and reuse it:

```
mail = Rails.cache.fetch("newsletters/#{newsletter.id}") do 
  NewsletterMailer.products(newsletter)
end

recipients.find_each do |user|
  mail.to = user.email
  mail.deliver
end
```

But with this code only first recipient receives email. Seems like that the same email can't be send more than once. Than I tried to dup it:

```
recipients.find_each do |user|
  m = mail.dup
  m.to = user.email
  m.deliver
end
```

The same result. Just to check this assumption instead of dup I tried:

```
m = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(mail))
```

Then email is delivered to all recipients.

So my question is how can "reset" (or smth like that) email and send it again?

ActionMailer version is 3.1.12

UPD

The problem was that emails had the same 'Message-ID' header. In development I was using GMail and don't know exactly ActionMailer or GMail wasn't sending. At the moment I don't have opportunity to test it.
Anyway same 'Message-ID' is incorrect so I added `add_message_id` to generate new header for each email:

```
recipients.find_each do |user|
  mail.add_message_id
  mail.to = user.email
  mail.deliver
end
```

Maybe someone will find it helpful or someone can give a clearer explanation.

I haven't tried Peer Allan's answer. But it seems like that it also can be solution, that's why I accepted it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the data in the email does not need to change for each recipient you could try to send the email [without using templates](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#sending-emails-without-template-rendering).

```rb
# determine a way to get the email body into a string
email_body = NewsletterMailGenerator.generate_email(newsletter)

recipients.find_each do |user|
  NewsletterMailer.products(user.email, email_body).deliver
end

class NewsletterMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def products(user, email_body)
    mail(to: user,
         body: email_body,
         content_type: "text/html",
         subject: "Already rendered!")
  end
end
```

Sample mailer code is from here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#sending-emails-without-template-rendering